# What character playstyle most resembles Bryan Fury in Tekken?

Tags: super-street-fighter-iv, tekken

More specifically, I like to be able to engage very quickly and very powerfully if my opponent makes a mistake. In the meantime, I like methodically advancing my position and dealing good, safe damage with my normals. Good focus/throw/slide is a plus, I abuse those. I'm definitely pretty bad at this point, but I want to pick a character whose playstyle I won't hate as my skills grow.

I have a few characters I'm leaning towards, but I'm looking for confirmation so I won't mention them until after I get a good round of responses.

Thanks! =)

EDIT: I ended up choosing Guy. He's versatile offensively with a strong mix-up game and the ability to engage quickly, forcing conflict.

Comment: What does the "slf" mean at the beginning of your question title?

Comment: I'm asking the question at another site as well, that's an artifact of the copy+paste. Edited out now!

Comment: What's the "ttt" tag you made? Do you mean `Tekken-Tag-Tournament`?

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes That would be my guess. I've edited the tag out for now, sice **ttt** is a rather meaningless tag. Deceny can add it back in with a more meaningful name when he wishes.

Comment: Tekken-tag-tournament is an equally meaningless tag, seeing as this is the only question for it and it has no followers, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up choosing Guy. A few months later, I still feel he was a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

EventHubs has a good overview of the cast. I recommend you to do some of the trials and spend some time on training to feel the character's style.

Maybe **Cody**.

Cody is a heavy-hitting frame-trapping rock-throwing tank of destruction.

**Strengths**

- Deadly firepower, can stun quickly.
- Great normal anti-airs.
- Far-reaching punish game.
- Easy combos into damaging Ultra 1.
- Projectiles have very fast recovery.
- Incredible range and damage on his overhead attack.
- Large amounts of frame advantage on all normal moves.

**Weaknesses**

- Extremely limited options on wakeup and against pressure.
- Very slow walk speed.
- Short range on backdash.
- Projectile can't win fireball wars.
- Tough time chipping opponents safely.

For more character, take a look at:

http://www.eventhubs.com/guides/2008/jul/08/street-fighter-4-strategy-guide-hints-and-tips/

Comment: I've done the first ~10 trials for each character, I'm leaning towards Guy right now. Others that I've enjoyed are Fei-Long, but I will give Cody a try in some real games too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A few come to mind:

Balrog's play style is pretty similar to Brian, with very punishing hits to take advantage of miscues.  Not many kicks though.

Guile is also a good fit, he has some very strong normal combos and strong defense.